# Magento Payment Module like PayPal (external URL redirect)

Tags: magento, post, redirect, external, payment

i need help in magento payment module programming.
I want to develop a payment module for magento which should working like the "PayPal Standard Payment".

The Module in the backend is done. I can choose my new module and can activate/deactivate it.
In The Frontend i see my new payment-type on the Payment-Information site.

**Now, the next step which i don't know how to start it is, to tell magento, when my new payment-type is chosen and the order is placed, redirect to the acquirers site(and send chosen data with POST-form), where the customer can fill his credit card informations and so on.**

I have searched for information and tutorials but still not found any good tutorials.

Thanks a lot for any helpful answers,
brush51

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to Mage_Checkout_OnepageController and in savePaymentAction you can see that it loads the redirect url in session.

So what you need to do is, you implement in your payment model the method getCheckoutRedirectUrl() which basically returns the url from config or from hard coded value.

Magento will handle the rest.

Comment: At first thank you for your answer.I have tried the hard coded option, but other payments doenst work after that. Can you explain me how to solve it with Module, Controller POST data to URL..? Actually i want build a payment module like Paypal - redirect URL, POST data and turn back to magento shop. Any tutorials to change the paypal payment module?